# Recommended .gitignore for react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm trying out react native and `eject`ed into a full build environment. Sadly, the eject-script did not create a sensible `.gitignore` file.

Not knowing a lot about app-development, I wonder what directories I could `.gitignore` here?

I'm guessing:

- `android/build`
- `android/app/build`
- `android/.gradle/`

Are these alright, or are there any more directories I should `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Below is the `.gitignore` file ships with the `react-native init` command. You can find the full file [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/586de42d9097c7b7d5eb49de552a032aee507e89/packages/react-native/template/_gitignore#L4).

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml

# node.js
#
node_modules/
package-lock.json # include if you are using npm - don't use both yarn and npm
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
yarn.lock # include if you are using yarn - don't use both npm and yarn

# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore

# Fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use Fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/

*/fastlane/report.xml
*/fastlane/Preview.html
*/fastlane/screenshots

# Bundle artifact
*.jsbundle
```

Comment: package-lock.json or yarn.lock should be commited

Comment: You should definitely commit one of the `lock` files. If you are using `npm` it should be `package-lock.json` and if you are using `yarn` it should be `yarn.lock`.

Comment: does this add the pod files as well?

Comment: Doesn't preserve for me all Xcode required project's settings... Not sure what is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does android/app/build get ignored by above git ignore ?

Comment: why can't we add these `android/build
android/app/build
android/.gradle/` in gitignore it takes longer to push update

Comment: @Ankita no it doesn't i guess.

Comment: why there is no `ios/build`?

Comment: What about `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist`? Those contain some information such as client ID, API Key, Google App ID. That's a case when incorporating `Firebase`.

Comment: Link is broken :/

Answer (score -1):

This is what I am using.

The content should be save in the .gitignore after ios and android envirment like (signature, config file) init,

Then the auto generate file like (index.android.bundle,main.jsbundle) need to be removed using git rm -f ---cached (file path) ,then commit it,then create a new one.

That's becasue the auto generate file don't need to be commited.

```
node_modules/**/*
.expo/*
npm-debug.*
*.jks
*.p8
*.p12
*.key
*.mobileprovision
*.orig.*
web-build/
package-lock.json
# macOS
.DS_Store
ios/
ios/*
ios/main.jsbundle
ios/**/*
android/
android/*
android/**/*

.vs/
*.log

# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml
*.hprof

# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore
!debug.keystore

# Bundle artifacts
*.jsbundle

# CocoaPods
/ios/Pods/

# Expo
.expo/
web-build/
```

Comment: you are ignoring all files inside `android/`? and why ignoring the `package-lock.json`? that seems wrong.

Comment: @caesarsol because the android file is somewhat  unchanged,  It's all about config files for different phones. Next, package-lock.json should not be  ignored , but it's an auto generated file, or it all depends on your like, I am not sure.

Comment: yes but you will ignore all future changes in that directory, and that is probably not what you want...  about the `package-lock.json`, it [should be absolutely committed](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#description) :)

Answer (score -3):

This is the newer version of .gitignore for react-native projects
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/.gitignore

Adding package manager lock file is optional. You can add them by adding `package-lock.json` for npm or `yarn.lock` for yarn, at the end of the below code.

```
# Xcode
!**/*.xcodeproj
!**/*.pbxproj
!**/*.xcworkspacedata
!**/*.xcsettings
!**/*.xcscheme
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

# Gradle
/build/
/RNTester/android/app/build/
/RNTester/android/app/gradle/
/RNTester/android/app/gradlew
/RNTester/android/app/gradlew.bat
/ReactAndroid/build/

# Buck
.buckd
buck-out
/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib/armeabi-v7a/
/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib/x86/
/ReactAndroid/src/main/gen

# Watchman
.watchmanconfig

# Android
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml
/android/

# Node
node_modules
*.log
.nvm
/bots/node_modules/
package-lock.json

# OS X
.DS_Store

# Test generated files
/ReactAndroid/src/androidTest/assets/AndroidTestBundle.js
*.js.meta

/coverage
/third-party

# Root dir shouldn't have Xcode project
/*.xcodeproj

# ReactCommon subdir shouldn't have Xcode project
/ReactCommon/**/*.xcodeproj
RNTester/build

# Libs that shouldn't have Xcode project
/Libraries/FBLazyVector/**/*.xcodeproj
/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec/**/*.xcodeproj
/Libraries/RCTRequired/**/*.xcodeproj
/React/CoreModules/**/*.xcodeproj
/packages/react-native-codegen/**/*.xcodeproj

# CocoaPods
/template/ios/Pods/
/template/ios/Podfile.lock
/RNTester/Gemfile.lock

# Ignore RNTester specific Pods, but keep the __offline_mirrors__ here.
RNTester/Pods/*
!RNTester/Pods/__offline_mirrors

# react-native-codegen
/ReactCommon/fabric/components/rncore/
/schema-rncore.json
```

Comment: This is the actual react-native repositories gitignore. See the accepted answer's link for an example template for react native projects.